# Can I ensure programs not overlap the Windows 7 gadgets?

Tags: windows-7

When any application maximizes, it overlaps the Windows sidebar.

How can I keep the Windows sidebar visible and make sure it doesn't get overlapped?

Comment: There's no "SideBar" in Windows 7.  Do you mean the Task Bar (the one with the Start Button)?

Comment: There *is* a sidebar in 7; unless the container that the gadgets are stored in goes by a different term. (Yes, I know that there is no physical container for the gadgets like the rectangular window in Vista, but that's just semantics; a novice user sees the collection of gadgets in the same place as belonging to a single unit; it's one of the Gestalt principles.)

Comment: True, it's there running the gadgets, but as you say it's not a visible container, so I don't think the OP is complaining it's covered. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Windows 7 no longer has a 'sidebar' in the way that Vista did. The sidebar was removed in favour of desktop gadgets and there is no way to keep them (as a group) on top.

What you can do is right click each gadget and select "Always on top" to keep particular gadgets above other windows.